# Converting char to binary file

Tags: c, char

I have a homework assignment where I want to take a `char*` (`string`) and turn it into a `uint8_t` (`byte`) i then want to split the byte into two `nibbles` (`4bits`) and edit it and write it to a binary file. What would be the best way of doing this? How do you take a `char` and turn it to a `uint8_t`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please post what have you tried so far and take a look at how to ask good questions: [ask]

Comment: You need to make your question clearer. It sounds a if the input is a character such as '2' and you want to convert it from the ASCII value that means 2 (0x32) into the binary value 2. Alternatively, you might want to actually process the binary value 0x32. Which one do you actually mean to do?

Answer (score 3):

`char` and `uint8_t` are almost the same (can be the same, depending on compiler settings; `char` has compiler switch dependent signedness). Just cast to ensure the correct signedness before operating:

```
char someval = mystring[0];
uint8_t lonyb = (uint8_t)someval & 0xF;
uint8_t hinyb = (uint8_t)someval >> 4;
```

Comment: I think that he wants to take the string and covert it to a binary digit so that '2' becomes 2 rather than the ASCII code which means 2.

Comment: thanks ShadowRanger yes that is what I meant, thank you for your help!